# How can I check if an application or WebView has the appropriate permission to invoke a plugin in Android?

Tags: android, webview, android-ndk, npapi, browser-plugin

I have a `netscape-based(NPAPI)` `plugin` packed in a .so file inside an apk. Various WebViews may invoke this `plugin`, if their webpage has the required `MIME` type.

But, I also want to `restrict` the plugin's usage to only those who have the permissions to do so.How can I check this at the plugin side?

I've tried implementing the `AndroidManifest.xml` `<permissions>` and `<uses-permissions>` and it does not seem to enforce a check at all.

Comment: What kind of permission would this exactly be, that you tried in your AndroidManifest

Comment: @StefandeBruijn:  I used the <permissions> tag to set the permission in the plugin's apk and used the <uses-permission> tag in the calling WebView. The invoking happens irrespective of whether permission exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

`<uses-permissions>` in AndroidManifest.xml is for your app to be able to access system or other apps' APIs.

`<permissions>` is for your app to limit the target apps to access APIs (receiver action...) by your own app.

If you are asking about how not to let other apps to use your .so file. Then I would tell you that it is not necessary. In Android, every application is sandboxed. Other apps are not able to use your library .so file.

If you are asking about how to let some WebView in your app use the library while not to let others do, then I would say that `permission` is not what you are looking for. Why don't you just have an attribute to indicate whether the webview needs the plugin or not.